# How to create a summation function with data frame in R?

Tags: r, function, loops, iteration, calculator

Just for fun, I am trying to create a basic savings calculator. My current code is:

```
value <- function(years,apr,initial,investment) {
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = years, ncol = 2))
colnames(df) <- c("year","value")
df$years <- c(1:years)
  for (i in 1:years) {
    current_value <-(last_value+investment)*apr 
  }
#repeating calculation for the data frame
print(df)
```

What I am trying to do is have the calculator create a table that displays the value each year. I've adapted my code from an old homework assignment, so I am not concerned with how to make the data frame. However, I do not know how to make the formula for the summation.

I am trying to model

Current Value = (Cumulative Value + Investment)*(Annual Percentage Rate)

As an example, let's say initial value is 10, investment is 10, and the APR is 1.05

(10+10)*(1.05)=21

(21+10)*(1.05)=32.55

(32.55+10)*(1.05)=44.68

and so on.

Year is there to number the rows accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `Reduce` with `accumulate = TRUE`

```
calc_fun <- function(years,apr,initial,investment) {
   value <- Reduce(function(x, y) (x + investment) * y, rep(apr, year), initial, 
            accumulate = TRUE)
   data.frame(year = 0:year, value)
}

calc_fun(3, 1.05, 10, 10)
#  year   value
#1    0 10.0000
#2    1 21.0000
#3    2 32.5500
#4    3 44.6775
```

Using `for` loop we can do

```
calc_fun1 <- function(years,apr,initial,investment) {
   value <- numeric(years + 1)
   value[1] <- initial
   for (i in 1:years) value[i + 1] <- (value[i] + investment) * apr
   data.frame(year = 0:year, value)
}
```